# error occured when using df.fillna(0)

Tags: python, apache-spark

Very simple code using spark + python:

```
df = spark.read.option("header","true").csv(file_name)
df = df_abnor_matrix.fillna(0)
```

but error occured:

> pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u'Cannot resolve column name
>   "cp_com.game.shns.uc" among (ProductVersion, IMEI, FROMTIME, TOTIME,
>   STATISTICTIME, TimeStamp, label, MD5, cp_com.game.shns.uc,
>   cp_com.yunchang....

What's wrong with it? `cp_com.game.shns.uc` is among the list.

Answer (score 0):

Spark does not support dot character in column names, [check issue](https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/spark-issues/201511.mbox/%3CJIRA.12916010.1448420265000.186431.1448420290969@Atlassian.JIRA%3E), so you need to replace dots with underscore before working on the csv.